# Is it possible to execute a Zap by calling an API and get the JSON response?

Tags: api, zapier, pipedream

As explained in their [documentation](https://zapier.com/help/create/code-webhooks/trigger-zaps-from-webhooks#limitations), it is not possible to customize the response of Zapier webhooks.

I want something like [Pipedream's HTTP API trigger](https://pipedream.com/docs/workflows/steps/triggers/#http), it exposes a custom API. You can hit and retrieve the data from the workflow and can return a custom response as per your needs.

Is there any way I can do the same with Zapier?

Comment: zapier doesn't support trigger API feature at this moment

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with Zapier at this time.